# Adding segments3d to a view 3D from lidr

Tags: lidr

I want to add segments represent the tree of apex tree, how to add `segments3d` to the plot below ?

```
library(lidR)
library(rgl)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyz", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")

ttops <- tree_detection(las, lmf(ws = 5))

plot(las) %>%
  add_treetops3d(ttops) %>%
  segments3d(...)
```

What are arguments of ... ?

Comment: I guess that you want to plot tree trunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point here is that the point cloud is not rendered with actual XY coordinates because `rgl` is working with `float` instead of `double` and this create artifacts when displaying the point cloud. The coordinates are thus shifted to get a nice rendering.

To display your segments you must shift their coordinates as well. `plot` returns the offset values applied. In the following example I assumed that you wanted to plot the trunks of the trees

```r
library(lidR)
library(rgl)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyz", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")

ttops <- tree_detection(las, lmf(ws = 5))

x = coordinates(ttops)[,1]
y = coordinates(ttops)[,2]
z = ttops$Z

offset = plot(las)
add_treetops3d(offset, ttops)

xoffset = offset[1]
yoffset = offset[2]

for (i in 1:length(ttops))  
{
  X = c(x[i], x[i]) - xoffset
  Y = c(y[i], y[i]) - yoffset
  Z = c(0, z[i])
  segments3d(X, Y, Z, col = "white", size = 2)
}
```